# mongodb native driver seems to be ignoring readPreference=nearest

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to setup a mongodb replica set in 3 different data centers. So I have 3 servers which connected to a private network through VPN. Let's say they are:

> server A: 10.*.*.1 (data center in my country, secondary)
>   server B: 10.*.*.88 (my office, primary)
>   server C: 10.*.*.10 (oversea data center, secondary)

And my program is also deployed in 3 data servers. I also set the `readPreference` to `nearest` in my connection string to get best performance. However, I still find the program on server `A` runs very slow. So I set profiling level to 2 on my primary instance

```
db.setProilingLevel(2)
```

Surprisingly, I find the query from application on server `A` is accessing server `B` to fetch data (sometimes server `C` too I guess, because it get very slow sometimes). 
I also tried to hard code `readPreference`=`nearest` in my code. doesn't work either.

So why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

some additional information which maybe useful:
**replica set information:**

```
img:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "img",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:36:30.481Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "internal.myserver.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 356160,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1441704113, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:21:53Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1441589586, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-07T01:33:06Z"),
            "configVersion" : 9,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "img.myserver.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 115567,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1441704113, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:21:53Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:36:29.742Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:36:28.558Z"),
            "pingMs" : 33,
            "syncingTo" : "internal.myserver.com:27017",
            "configVersion" : 9
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "us.img.myserver.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 6126,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1441704113, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:21:53Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:36:29.006Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-08T09:36:30.153Z"),
            "pingMs" : 497,
            "syncingTo" : "internal.myserver.com:27017",
            "configVersion" : 9
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**host information:**

```
[root@SERVER_B image-server]# ping internal.myserver.com
PING internal.myserver.com (10.*.*.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from internal.myserver.com (10.*.*.88): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.78 ms

[root@SERVER_B image-server]# ping img.myserver.com
PING img.myserver.com (10.*.*.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from img.myserver.com (10.*.*.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms

[root@SERVER_B image-server]# ping us.img.myserver.com
PING us.img.myserver.com (10.*.*.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from us.img.myserver.com (10.*.*.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=195 ms
```

**nodejs information:**

```
[root@iZ94s1agmdlZ image-server]# node -v
v0.10.36
```

I'm using node native driver 2.0.42

Comment: Are you talking about you "application" or are you talking about "which server is reading from which in replication?". You mention *"Query from server A to server B"* which does not indicate the "query" is coming from your application. Replication generally comes from the "primary" unless you explicitly state otherwise. And if that is your question then you are "off-topic" for a programming questions site and need to post to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven sorry for the confusion. I'm referring to my application, not the server. because the application is deployed on the same server as mongod is. I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I finally find that it's a problem of GridStore only. Even if I specified readPreference=nearest in connection string (it actually worked for other queries except `GridStore`), GridStore somehow doesn't get this setting from connection string.
To workaround, while initializing GridStore specify `options`

```
{
  ReadPreference.NEAREST
}
```

this would do the magic. I will report this bug to official JIRA.

nodejs driver **2.0.39**